# How to select more option in a dropdown with array of value using php?

Tags: php

How to select a multiple choices of array in a dropdown using php.

Input :

```
<?php
$val = "22,33,55";
?>
<select name="choice" multiple="true">
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
<option value="44">44</option>
<option value="55">55</option>
</select>
```

I want the Output like:

```
<select name="choice" multiple="true">
<option value="11">11</option>
**<option value="22">22</option>**
**<option value="33">33</option>**
<option value="44">44</option>
**<option value="55">55</option>**
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `select`? Are you trying to parse HTML?

Comment: What you mean by multiple type choice of array?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
$val = "22,33,55";
$valarray = explode(',',$val);
?>


<select name="choice" multiple="true">
<option value="11" >11</option>
**<option value="22" <?php if(in_array(22,$valarray)){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>22</option>**
**<option value="33" <?php if(in_array(33,$valarray)){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>33</option>**
<option value="44">44</option>
**<option value="55" <?php if(in_array(55,$valarray)){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>55</option>**
</select>
```

Comment: Personally I would use multiple check-boxes, but there's nothing wrong with dropdown ;)

Comment: Please now check my answer hope it's useful for you

Comment: someone removed comment above mine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

First of all, change $val into array. Then is select options use in_array() ( http://www.php.net/in_array ) to validate if you need to print selected="selected" in give option.

I guess thats the easiest option

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
   <?php 
  $selected_value = "22,33,55";
  $selected_value = explode(',', $selected_value);
  $all_values = array(11,22,33,44,55); ?>
  <select name="choice[]" multiple="multiple"> <?php
  foreach($all_values as $option_value ) { 
    $selected = '';
    if(in_array($option_value, $selected_value)){
      $selected = "selected";
    }?>
    <option <?php echo $selected; ?> ><?php echo $option_value; ?></option><?php
  } ?>
   </selected
```